# Opening an protect external page inside our web application

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a secure c# asp.net mvc web application and inside a view I want to load an externa url (geckoboard dashboard). What I have done right now is to use an Iframe like:

```
<iframe src="https://sample.geckoboard.com/dashboard/test1232121" style="position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:100%; border:none; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; z-index:999999;">Your browser doesn't support IFrames</iframe>
```

But the sideback is if the user view the source page he could just copy the url from the iframe source and place it in a browser to see it directly, so I want to hide or obfuscate.

I was thinking also in maybe making a webrequest to the url and get the HTML and put the response into a div but because geckoboard uses a lot of javascripts that runs on their domain im pretty sure I will mess with the dashboard.

Any advice or recomendation on what is the best way to solve this?

Comment: Any savvy user will be able to tell what you are doing. It's not really possible.

Comment: Ok, what I did was to obfuscate the script using jquery. I think that will work. Thanks a lot

Comment: as long as you understand that it will be very easy to bypass and you are not relying on it.

Answer (score 0):

If its opening a http connection, the user will always have the ability to view the source in the browser, even monitoring the network using a number of tools including google's developer tools built into chrome will show them that this is happening.

There are no 'good' ways to prevent the user from seeing content that you are asking his browser to download and display, and for good reason.